# Recursive search function which narrows down results on each iteration

Tags: php, function, recursion, search

I want to write a search function that can recursively search an array and narrow down the results on each iteration. The idea is that it finds a first set of results, then continues with that result and searches it again to find the next set of results. The search criteria is provided as an array with needles. I have already a basic function going, but results are not as expected.

I have written the recursive function which is working. However the  iterations does not give me my final result.

```
$array = array(
    0 => array('id' => 1, 'currency' => 'EUR', 'name' => 'NL', 'country_code' => 31), 
    1 => array('id' => 2, 'currency' => 'EUR', 'name' => 'DE', 'country_code' => 49),
    2 => array('id' => 3, 'currency' => 'EUR', 'name' => 'FR', 'country_code' => 33),
    3 => array('id' => 4, 'currency' => 'EUR', 'name' => 'BE', 'country_code' => 32),
    4 => array('id' => 5, 'currency' => 'USD', 'name' => 'US', 'country_code' => 1),
    5 => array('id' => 6, 'currency' => 'Rand', 'name' => 'SAF', 'country_code' => 27),
    6 => array('id' => 7, 'currency' => 'Rubbles', 'name' => 'RUS', 'country_code' => 7),
    7 => array('id' => 8, 'currency' => 'EUR', 'name' => 'IT', 'country_code' => 39),
    8 => array('id' => 9, 'currency' => 'Pound', 'name' => 'GB', 'country_code' => 44),
); //list of countries which needs to searched

$query = array('currency' => 'EUR', 'id' => 8, 'country_code' => 49); //search needles

function _searchData(array $array, array $query, $counter=0) 
{
  $result = array();
  $matches_found = array();

  if($array){
     $i = $counter; //set counter, start with 0
     $keys = array_keys($query); //get query keys
     $vals = array_values($query); //get query values
     $max = count($keys); //set max_count to limit iteration

     foreach($array as $arrkey => $arrval){
       if(isset($arrval[$keys[$i]]) && $arrval[$keys[$i]] == $vals[$i] && $i < $max){ 
         $matches_found = $this->_searchData($arrval, $query, $i++); //return result, increment counter
         if($matches_found){    
           $arrval = $matches_found; //overwrite result array           
          }
       $result[] = $arrval;  
     }
   }
  return $result;
}
Expected result = 
**it should fail on the 3rd iteration because "country_code" does not match 
on result id 8.
```

I think my main problem is with the counter, as it needs to be increased. Within the foreach loop I am not able to get full control. I have tries storing matches_found and re-use it outside the loop, but that does not work either.

The goal of the function is to narrow down the result on each iteration to end with a final set of result as it matches fewer key value pairs. Ps maybe there is an easier way to search an array with a large set of needles, and i am always open for other suggestions, but my main goal is to get this recursive function going as it makes the most sense to me to achieve my desired results. Also in terms of flexibility as I can have as many search needles as wanted. I hope someone can set me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you put the input array and expected output array to your question? Without it we don't know what you're searching for in the described array.

Comment: Hi CodiMech25, thanks for your quick reply. I have added the main array that needs to be searched. Thanks for looking at my problem.

Comment: Not idea what you're trying to accomplish with recursion here, but I already see a suspicious part of your code. When entering another level of recursion, you're supposed to pass the argument as `$i + 1` not `$i++`.

Comment: Hi Ultimater, thanks for that piece of advice. I have have tested it. The counter gets incremented correctly, however not yet the desired result. Basically I want the function to narrow down results, so it starts with e.g. 5 results as it finds 'currency' => 'EUR', then that array is send back into the function searching for the next set of results based on 'id' => 8, which end up to be 1 result. I want to add as much search values as wanted, as it loops, it narrows the result down. Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do a lot simpler given your requirements, e.g.:

```
<?php

$in = [
    ['id' => 1, 'currency' => 'EUR',     'name' => 'NL'],
    ['id' => 2, 'currency' => 'EUR',     'name' => 'DE'],
    ['id' => 3, 'currency' => 'EUR',     'name' => 'FR'],
    ['id' => 4, 'currency' => 'EUR',     'name' => 'BE'],
    ['id' => 5, 'currency' => 'USD',     'name' => 'US'],
    ['id' => 6, 'currency' => 'Rand',    'name' => 'SAF'],
    ['id' => 7, 'currency' => 'Rubbles', 'name' => 'RUS'],
    ['id' => 8, 'currency' => 'EUR',     'name' => 'IT'],
    ['id' => 9, 'currency' => 'Pound',   'name' => 'GB'],
];

$query = ['currency' => 'EUR', 'id' => 8]; //search needles

// array_filter will use the given callback to check every entry
$out = array_filter($in, function(array $candidate) use ($query) {
    // iterate over query
    foreach ($query as $key => $predicate) {
        // if the key exists, but the value differs
        if (isset($candidate[$key]) && $candidate[$key] !== $predicate) {
            // it should not be included
            return false;
        }
    }

    // otherwise, include
    return true;
});

print_r($out);
```

demo: https://3v4l.org/aAZPP

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Hi Yoshi, thanks for your answer. Agreed this looks much simpler. I only run into issues when I am starting to add a third needle. If it matches the second needle and fails the third needle, it will still be included as a good result. So this is not exactly the desired result. I will update my input array because it has much more values, i just trimmed it down so it was much easier to read. One moment...

Comment: @DFA I'm not sure I understand. Given your new inputs, the code gives an empty array as result. That's to be expected, as no entry matches all requirements?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i was using the wrong input array. I see it working now, thanks! Will accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: Yoshi, I need to ask, when I use integers it returns the result, when using number string it does not? Is this expected behavior for array_filter. Sorry for my noob question. Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it using: $query = array_map('strval', $query); Now works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @DFA I'd say that's only indirectly connected to `array_filter` in this example. Inside the callback I'm using strict comparison `$candidate[$key] !== $predicate` to avoid type coercion. Which results in  (for example) the string `"42"` to **not be equal** to the integer `42`. For reference: https://www.php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php